# Find complexity for rewritten DFS

Tags: time-complexity, pseudocode

For the following question:

> By given N stations, source station, destination station, data structure that represents all the possible paths between every 2 stations (paths are undirected) and the length of every path from one station to another – Find the longest path from source station the destination station

I wrote the following pseudo-code:

```
Vertex
    String key
    boolean visited
    LinkedList<Edge>nextEdges


Edge
    Vertext nextVertex
    int length

    tempSum=0
    stack
    maxSum=0
    maxPath
    maxPathByDFS(src,dst)

1        stack.push(src)
2        src.visited=true
3        if (!src.nextEdges.isEmpty)
4            for (currEdge∶src.nextEdges)

5                if (currEdge.nextVertex==dst)
6                    tempSum+=currEdge.lenght
7                    stack.push(dst)
8                    if(tempSum>maxSum)
9                        maxSum=tempSum
10                        stack.toArray(maxPath)
11                    stack.pop
12                    tempSum-=currEdge.lenght
13                else if (!currEdge.nextVertex.visited)
14                    tempSum+=currEdge.lenght
15                    maxPathByDFS(currEdge.nextVertex,dst)
16                    tempSum-=currEdge.lenght
17        stack.pop
18        src.visited=false
19        return
```

Could you please help me to find the run-time complexity of my solution?

Comment: complexity depends on the number of edges which cannot be described by means of the number of nodes - there could be any number of edges between any pair of nodes. the only well-known fact here is that the longest path problem is NP-hard, i.e. it doesn't have a polynomial solution unless NP=P